# Вывод изображений разделов инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть инофблок catalog_tovar, у него есть разделы: товары для дома, товары для магазина. Каждому разделу заданы изображения, как их вывести?

```
             <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:catalog",
"catalog_viziton",
Array(
    "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
    "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
    "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "-",
    "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "N",
    "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
    "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
    "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
    "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
    "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/basket.php",
    "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
    "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "catalog_viziton",
    "DETAIL_ADD_DETAIL_TO_SLIDER" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_EMAIL_NOTIFY" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_URL" => "catalog_comments",
    "DETAIL_BLOG_USE" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_BRAND_USE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "DETAIL_CHECK_SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_DETAIL_PICTURE_MODE" => "IMG",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE" => "E",
    "DETAIL_FB_USE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "DETAIL_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"127",1=>"128",2=>"map",3=>"ATT_ADDRESS",4=>"ATT_WORKING_TIME",5=>"ATT_CONTACTS",6=>"ATT_ORGANIZATION",7=>"ATT_TEL",8=>"ATT_EMAIL",9=>"ATT_CARDORG",10=>"LOGO_ENTERPRISE",11=>"",),
    "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
    "DETAIL_USE_COMMENTS" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_USE_VOTE_RATING" => "Y",
    "DETAIL_VK_USE" => "N",
    "DETAIL_VOTE_DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => "rating",
    "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "VERTICAL",
    "FORUM_ID" => "9",
    "IBLOCK_ID" => "28",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog_viziton",
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
    "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
    "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "LINK_ELEMENTS_URL" => "link.php?PARENT_ELEMENT_ID=#ELEMENT_ID#",
    "LINK_IBLOCK_ID" => "",
    "LINK_IBLOCK_TYPE" => "",
    "LINK_PROPERTY_SID" => "",
    "LIST_BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
    "LIST_META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
    "LIST_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
    "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "MESSAGES_PER_PAGE" => "10",
    "MESSAGE_404" => "",
    "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
    "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
    "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнение",
    "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
    "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
    "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
    "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
    "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
    "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
    "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
    "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "30",
    "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
    "PATH_TO_SMILE" => "/bitrix/images/forum/smile/",
    "PRICE_CODE" => array(0=>"raiting",),
    "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "N",
    "PRICE_VAT_SHOW_VALUE" => "N",
    "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
    "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(),
    "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
    "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "",
    "REVIEW_AJAX_POST" => "Y",
    "SECTIONS_SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
    "SECTIONS_VIEW_MODE" => "LIST",
    "SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
    "SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "Y",
    "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
    "SECTION_TOP_DEPTH" => "2",
    "SEF_FOLDER" => "/katalog/",
    "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
    "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array("sections"=>"","section"=>"#SECTION_ID#","element"=>"#SECTION_ID#/#ELEMENT_ID#/","compare"=>"","smart_filter"=>"#SECTION_ID#",),
    "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
    "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
    "SHOW_404" => "N",
    "SHOW_DEACTIVATED" => "N",
    "SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM" => "N",
    "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
    "SHOW_TOP_ELEMENTS" => "Y",
    "SIDEBAR_DETAIL_SHOW" => "Y",
    "SIDEBAR_PATH" => "",
    "SIDEBAR_SECTION_SHOW" => "Y",
    "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "9",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
    "TOP_ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
    "TOP_LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
    "TOP_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(0=>"",1=>"",),
    "TOP_VIEW_MODE" => "SECTION",
    "URL_TEMPLATES_READ" => "/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=message&FID=#FORUM_ID#&TID=#TOPIC_ID#&MID=#MESSAGE_ID#",
    "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
    "USE_COMPARE" => "N",
    "USE_ELEMENT_COUNTER" => "Y",
    "USE_FILTER" => "N",
    "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
    "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
    "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "N",
    "USE_REVIEW" => "Y",
    "USE_STORE" => "N"
)
```

);?>

Comment: Размещение кода подключения комплексного компонента не поможет ровным счетом ничем. Открывайте файлы шаблона, ищите где выводится нужная вам инфа и правьте.

Comment: а какое свойство свойство связано с выводом картинки раздела инф.блока?

Comment: всё решил,  в разделе catalog.section.list/.default/template.php задал вывод картинки

Comment: Тогда напишите подробный ответ для других ищущих, на будущее.

Answer (score 2):

Для вывод изображений разделов инфоблока нужно попасть в файл template.php находящийся по пути /bitrix/templates/шаблон/components/bitrix/catalog/название компонента /bitrix/catalog.section.list/.default . Далее в нужном для вас месте прописать `<img src="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>`

Answer (score 0):

В template.php вашего шаблона сайта в компоненте catalog.section.list

для вывода изображения раздела "превью":

```
<img src="<?=$arSection["PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"/>
```

для вывода изображения раздела "детальной":

```
<?$arItemR = CFile::GetFileArray($arSection['DETAIL_PICTURE']);?>
<img src="<?=$arItemR['SRC']?>"/>
```